# Redux - thunkMiddleware - dispatch as an extra argument doesn't work

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Why isn't dispatch read in fetchit()?

- thunkMiddleware is added to applyMiddleware
- introduce dispatch to fetchit in mapDispatchToProps
- dispatch is added as an extra argument in fetchit()

*I can go around this and make it work in other ways like for example, initializing a global variable "dispatch" and in the component -> dispatch = useDispatch() ... and multiple other ways ...*

But I found online that doing it in this particular way should work, so I was wondering what is missing here...

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import loggerMiddleware from "redux-logger";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { useRef } from 'react';
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";


const ADD_TASK = "addTask";

const addTask = (task) => {return ({
    type: ADD_TASK,
    payload: task
})}

const reducer = (state=[], action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case ADD_TASK:
            return [...state, ...action.payload];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const store = createStore(reducer,  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware,loggerMiddleware));

const fetchit = (newTask="") =>(dispatch)=>{
    console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",dispatch);  // <<<<<<<<<<<< dispatch is not read
    if (!newTask){
        fetch("/get")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            dispatch(addTask(result.tasks));
        })
        .then(()=>{
            document.documentElement.scrollIntoView(false);
        })
    }
    else {
        fetch("/add", {
            credentials: "include",
            method: "POST",
            mode: "same-origin",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                //"X-CSRFToken": csrf
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newTask),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            if (result.task)
                dispatch(addTask([result.task]));            
        })
        .then(()=>{
            document.documentElement.scrollIntoView(false);
        })
    }
}

const Tasks = (props) => {
    const {state} = props;
    return [state.map(task => (
        <li key={task.id} style={{color:task.done?"blue":"red"}}>
            {task.task} <section style={{color:"black"}}>{task.description}</section>
            <section style={{color:"lightgray"}}>{task.dateTime}</section>
        </li>
    ))]
}

var firstFetch = true;
const App = (props) => {
    if (firstFetch){
        firstFetch = false;
        fetchit();
    }

    const inputTask = useRef(null);
    const inputDescription = useRef(null);
    const fetchNewInput = () => {
        let bodydict = {"task": inputTask.current.value, "description": inputDescription.current.value};
        fetchit(bodydict);
        inputTask.current.value = "";
        inputDescription.current.value = "";
    }
    return <>
        <h1>Tasks</h1>
        <ol>
            <Tasks state={props.state || []}/>
        </ol>
        <div>
            <input ref={inputTask}/>
            <textarea ref={inputDescription}></textarea>
            <button onClick={fetchNewInput}>ADD</button>
        </div>
    </>
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {state: state};
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {return {
    fetchit:(something)=> dispatch(fetchit(something)),
    addTask: (something) => dispatch(addTask(something)),
}}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

---

****The missed step --> extracting functions from props****
`const App = ({fetchit}) => {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this section:

```
 const fetchNewInput = () => {
    let bodydict = {"task": inputTask.current.value, "description": inputDescription.current.value};
    fetchit(bodydict);
    inputTask.current.value = "";
    inputDescription.current.value = "";
}
```

you are calling the thunk itself, while you should **dispatch fetchit**. you have access to dispatching fetchit via `props.fetchit`, as you defined in `mapDispatchToProps`

```
        props.fetchit(bodydict);
```

I guess the same naming got you confused.

also, you can dispatch addTask like this:

```
        props.addTask(task);
```